# Jmeter random number generation

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

I have a requirement to generate a random number and use it in subsequent requests. So, before using this newly generated random number in first subsequent request, i need to check if this random number generated is already exists in the application or not by comparing with newly generated response number. So for this validation i am thinking to use an extractor to get the count and eventually verify this is >1 and make it run until this condition is invalid. So in case of random number already exists, i need to generate a new random value since the previous one is already exist in the application. Any snippet i can use here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier option would be going for [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) which produces an [Unix timestamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/) in milliseconds from 1st of Jan 1970. To be on the safe side you can add [current thread number](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) to it so even in case of concurrency you would get unique values (incrementing each millisecond):

[image]

More information on JMeter Functions concept: [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction)